# Pass Object while mocking methods in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have following method for which I am writing unit test:

```
public void myMethod(){
   String url = "post url";

   HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   //adding attributes to httpHeaders object

   ServiceCallDto serviceCallDto = new ServiceCallDto();
   //adding attributes to serviceCallDto object for 1st call

   String body1 = httpService.post(url, httpHeaders, serviceCallDto);

   serviceCallDto = new ServiceCallDto();
   //adding attributes to serviceCallDto object for 2nd call

   String body2 = httpService.post(url, httpHeaders, serviceCallDto);

}
```

Here what I have tried to mock the method

```
public void myMethod(){
   ServiceCallDto serviceCallDto = new ServiceCallDto();
   //adding attributes to serviceCallDto object for 1st call
   when(httpService.post(anyString(), any(HttpHeaders.class), eq(serviceCall)))
    .thenReturn("Resopnse String"));
   
   serviceCallDto = new ServiceCallDto();
   //adding attributes to serviceCallDto object for 2nd call
   when(httpService.post(anyString(), any(HttpHeaders.class), eq(serviceCall)))
    .thenReturn("Resopnse String"));
```

but my method returns null value after calling post method, I believe the reason for this is here I am using serviceCallDto object which is created inside my test method.

Are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: Could you share how do you invoke the post call?

Comment: String response = httpService.post(url, httpHeaders, serviceCall);

Comment: url, httpHeaders and serviceCall objects are created inside the method

Comment: If you show the whole implementation class, and the whole test class, you are more likely to get an answer. Edit your question to include this information instead of the snippets of code.

Comment: Most likely, your ServiceCall objects are not equal. Did you implement `equals` correctly?

Comment: Hi Magnilex, I have edited the question

Comment: Hi Lesiak, I also believe that is the issue, Do I have to override the equals method inside my ServiceCallDto class, or is there any other way, because I have a complex object structure inside the object

Comment: I couldn't actually see, where you invoke the method. httpService.post(url, httpHeaders, serviceCallDto); should be called somewhere in the test.

Comment: You can also debug the code to know what causing the issue.

Comment: You need either an equals method, or an Argument Matcher.

Comment: Thanks, @Lesiak issue was fixed after implementing the equals method